# Samsung J5 (10) 2016 log

Tags: samsung

i have to check when my phone's "messages" app was accessed last night? i had 4 new messages but i have neither seen their notification on my mobile screen nor the small "4" written on messages app on home screen. i have tried other ways like checking if my phone's app was already opened/my friend's message conversation was opened and i slpt? no these are not the reasons of not receiving notification on screen because i have tested each of them by sending messages from other phone to my phone and in every case i got notification on screen.

Because i'm in a hostel and i doubt someone has checked my messages that's why i didn't see any notification this morning is there any way i can check at which times my messaging app was accessed? is there any system log for that? i need to check whether it was accessed between 4:00 AM to 6:AM today.

i'm using samsung J5 (10) 2GB ram. 16Gb rom. Android Version: 6.0.1

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked and answered before, but I can't find the original.

Comment: it would be great if you can give me the link?

Comment: also i have searched got some codes to dial and check but they didn't work

Comment: Yes, it would be great, but as I said, **I can't find** the original.

Comment: ok but in case you remember what was written in it any idea?